# How to prevent overlapping in react-chartjs-2 and make chart bar scrollable?

Tags: typescript, horizontal-scrolling, overlapping, react-chartjs-2

I am trying to draw a **bar chart** using **react-chartjs-2**, i am using **typescript**
because i have a big amount of data, there is overlapping in the chart, i want to **prevent overlapping**, instead of that, i want **horizontal scrolling**

my config is as follow:

```
// options
export const options = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      beginAtZero: 0,
      labelAutoFit: false,
      grid: {
        offset: false,
      },
    },
  },
};

// labels
const labels = [...new Array(200)].map((_, i) => i * 3);

// data
export const data = {
  labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: [...Array(200)].map(() => ~~(1 + Math.random() * 100)),
      backgroundColor: '#454547',
      barThickness: 8,
      barPercentage: 0.5,
      borderWidth: {
        top: 2,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
      },
      borderColor: ['white'],
    },
  ],
};
```

and my main function is as follow:

```
export default function FooterCpu() {
  return (
    <div className='max-h-[160px] '>
      <Bar className='myChart' options={options} data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

the result is as follow:
[bar chart with overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/766Oo.png)

anyone knows how can i prevent overlapping and instead of that make it horizontally scrollble?
thanx in advance